# Loading uncompressed js file in debug mode

Tags: file, joomla

Joomla has a feature where it loads the a minified javascript file and the uncompressed version when the site is in debug mode.

I have named both my files correctly and am include it as follows:

```
JHtml::_('script', JUri::root() . 'path_to_file/jquery-sortable.js');
```

When I put the site in debug mode, it does not load the uncompressed file.
However, If I use the following instead, it works fine:

```
JHtml::_('script', 'path_to_file/jquery-sortable.js');
```

Now I'm not sure whether this is a bug in Joomla or not, but I cannot find any information online regarding this. I would like to use `JURI::root()` in the path.

Does anyone have any information on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, if the script URL begins with `http`, the code that is responsible for including the uncompressed version (i.e, remove the `min.` segment if such exists or add `-uncompressed` otherwise) is ignored.

The source for this behavior:

`JHtml::includeRelativeFiles()` in `libraries/cms/html/html.php:298`

```php
protected static function includeRelativeFiles($folder, $file, $relative, $detect_browser, $detect_debug)
{
    // If http is present in filename
    if (strpos($file, 'http') === 0)
    {
        $includes = array($file);
    }
    else
        //process the script sourch.
    }
    ...
}
```

Most of the script files, including frameworks, are included as relative paths. I guess that this behavior is meant to prevent remote resources from getting 404ed.